# Combining several flags in PendingIntent.getBroadcast

Tags: android, android-intent, sms, android-pendingintent, smsmanager

Can we combine several PendingIntent flags like this?:

```
PendingIntent.getBroadcast(actvt, requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT|PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

I had some weird problems with pending intents, so I tried using used every possible precaution (somewhat blindly) to prevent those problems. As u can see I used requestCode in addition to two flags ORed together.

I studied the reference but found no indication if such a combination is legal or meaningful. Can someone please explain me that what are the implications of this code exactly?

Comment: `"I had some weird problems with pending intents"` what problems?

Comment: @pskink things like receiving previously received intents when program exited and then run again.

Comment: you cannot do that

Comment: you cannot do that, how can you receive previously received intents? received when? yesterday? a your ago?

Comment: @pskink probably my phone is somehow buggy! I have seen other strange repetitive behaviors in other parts of my program too. for example, in the case of a programming error and the resulting exception i see that that part of code is apparently executed several times (i discovered this by seeing the same Log.d messages from that code segment several times in logcat).